# C++ unexpected behaviour (where are my temporaries!?)

Tags: c++

This was an r-value experiment but it mutated when gcc whined to me about lack of move-constructor (I'd deleted it) and didn't fall-back to the copy constructor (as I expected)
I then removed -std=c++11 from the flags and tried what you see below, it has a lot of output (it didn't initially) because I am trying to work out why exactly it doesn't work (I know how to debug but I find messages on stdout to be a good indicator of something happening)

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object {
public:
    Object() { id=nextId; std::cout << "Creating object: "<<id<<"\n"; nextId++; }
    Object(const Object& from) {
         id=nextId; std::cout << "Creating object: "<<id<<"\n"; nextId++;
        std::cout<<"(Object: "<<id<<" created from Object: "<<from.id<<")\n";
    }
    Object& operator=(const Object& from) {
        std::cout<<"Assigning to "<<id<<" from "<<from.id<<"\n";
        return *this;
    }
    ~Object() { std::cout<<"Deconstructing object: "<<id<<"\n";}

private:
    static int nextId;
    int id;
};

int Object::nextId = 0;

Object test();

int main(int,char**) {
    Object a;
    std::cout<<"A ought to exist\n";
    Object b(test());
    std::cout<<"B ought to exist\n";
    Object c = test();
    std::cout<<"C ought to exist\n";
    return 0;
}


Object test() {
    std::cout<<"In test\n";
    Object tmp;
    std::cout<<"Test's tmp ought to exist\n";
    return tmp;
}
```

Output:

```
Creating object: 0
A ought to exist
In test
Creating object: 1
Test's tmp ought to exist
B ought to exist
In test
Creating object: 2
Test's tmp ought to exist
C ought to exist
Deconstructing object: 2
Deconstructing object: 1
Deconstructing object: 0
```

I use deconstructing, because deconstruction is already a word, sometimes I use destructor, I'm never quite happy with the word, I favour destructor as the noun.

Here's what I expected:

```
A to be constructed
tmp in test to be constructed, a temporary to be created from that 
    tmp, tmp to be destructed(?) 
that temporary to be the argument to B's copy constructor
the temporary to be destructed.
C's default constructor to be used
"" with a temporary from `test`
C's assignment operator to be used
the temporary to be destructed
c,b,a to be destructed.
```

I have been called "die-hard C" and I am trying to learn to use C++ as more than "C with namespaces".

Someone might say "the compiler optimises it out" I'd like that person never to answer a question with such an answer now or ever, optimisations must not alter the program state, it must be *as if* everything happened as the specification says, so the compiler may humor me by putting a message on cout that includes the number, it may not bother to even increase the number and such, but the output of the program would be the same as if it did do everything the code describes.

So it's not optimisations, what's going on?

Comment: "optimisations must not alter the program state, it must be as if everything happened as the specification says" In some cases c++ allowes the compiler to optimize out copies, **even if that would change observable behaviour**.

Comment: @BoBTFish under what conditions? Is there a proof that there is no situation where the observable behavior is required? (Forgive my desire of a formal definition, it's not me picking holes in your comment, I just wish to know more). I'd also love a link to the actual C++ specification, I found a first draft of C++11 but I'd like 98, 03 and 11 at least. Thanks

Comment: If you write a copy constructor that has side effects, it's a bug. It's like a die-hard C programmer putting an assignment in an ASSERT macro. It might work, but maybe next year you'll compile and it won't be there. In-place construction (ellision, RVO) is your friend, don't break it by writing a bad copy constructor that does more than copy. Those aren't the language's semantics.

Comment: @AlecTeal: the official standard docs are not freely available. They're for sale on the ISO and ANSI sites (among others), drafts are usually good enough though. Look up (N)RVO or "copy elision".

Comment: @BoBTFish I think that should be an answer (maybe referencing the relevant paragraphs in the standard).

Comment: @NicholasWilson I'm not sure why you put that "die hard" bit in there, I do hope it wasn't a dig about the amount of undefined behavior my kind rely on :P So the copy constructor ought not have side-effects, I have -wextra and -wall so why didn't GCC whine about it? I am glad by the way that optimisations exist, I did wonder why r-values came more than 2 decades later

Comment: @AlecTeal: C++11 12.8/31 gives the details of when elision can happen. It includes the words "even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects". There are no (legal) links to the published standard, but [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) is very close to it. As far as I know, [this](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2012) is the cheapest place to buy the published version.

Comment: @AlecTeal StackOverflow is not your blog, your question should be to the point and without opinions and stories. Please don't take my edit personally, it was done so anyone reading can comprehend your problem faster and provide an answer for you. I won't roll it back because I don't fancy an edit war, but I suggest you consider doing it.

Comment: @fish I will edit the post and post an answer that uses what I've learned later today (I must leave soon) I will tidy the question up then. I call this "standard slapping" btw, whenever someone on the GCC mailing list thinks they've found a bug, "std::bitchslap" as I call it is the usual response, I just got bitchslapped with the standard, recent example: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-08/msg00166.html bitchslap: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-08/msg00173.html I do think this is a better question than that edge case :P I was getting links when you posted that comment.

Answer (score 5):

It is an optimization, the only one that is allowed to alter observable behaviour of a program.

Here's the paragraph `12.8./31`, taken from standard draft n3337 (emphasis mine):

> When certain criteria are met, **an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.** In such cases,
>   the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different
>   ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of the times
>   when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization.
>   This elision of copy/move
>   operations, called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to 
>   eliminate multiple copies):
>
> > — in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
> >     non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-
> >     unqualiﬁed type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
> >     the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
> >
> > — in a throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a
> >     function or catch-clause parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost
> >     enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from the operand to the exception
> >     object (15.1) can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object
> >
> > — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
> >     to a class object with the same cv-unqualiﬁed type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
> >     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
> >
> > — when the exception-declaration of an exception handler (Clause 15) declares an object of the same type
> >     (except for cv-qualiﬁcation) as the exception object (15.1), the copy/move operation can be omitted
> >     by treating the exception-declaration as an alias for the exception object if the meaning of the program
> >     will be unchanged except for the execution of constructors and destructors for the object declared by
> >     the exception-declaration.
>
> [Example... omitted]

The semantics of a copy/move constructor are just that, copying/moving the contents of an object while initializing another one. If your copy constructors send emails with invitations to your birthday party you should not be surprised if you end up partying alone :)

OK, some copy constructors do other things, too. Think reference counting of a smart pointer. But if that gets optimized away, it's fine. There was no copy and nothing needed to be counted.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are experiencing Copy Elision.  And thus yes, it is optimizations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

> In C++ computer programming, copy elision refers to a compiler
>   optimization technique that eliminates unnecessary copying of objects.
>   The C++ language standard generally allows implementations to perform
>   any optimization, provided the resulting program's observable behavior
>   is the same as if, i.e. pretending, the program was executed exactly
>   as mandated by the standard.
>
> The standard also describes a few situations where copying can be
>   eliminated **even if this would alter the program's behavior**, the most
>   common being the return value optimization.

The emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 3):

Since copying/moving temporary objects has a cost, compilers are explicitly allowed to elide temporary objects, even if the corresponding constructors or destructors have side-effects. Copy/move elision is typically not considered an optimization and most compilers elide construction of temporary objects even in debug mode (which is reasonable as you don't want to have different behavior between debug and optimized builds).

The relevant clause in the C++11 standard is 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 31:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects. ...

The cases where copy/move elision is allowed are:

- in return statements
- in `throw` expressions
- when a temporary is not bound to a reference
- in the `catch` clause

The exact rules have a few extra conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent copy illision implement the assignment operator with the copy/swap algorithm like:

```
Object &operator =(Object other)
{
    std::swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

And then try:

```
Object a;
a = test();
```

That way the copy (or move) ctor will be called by the compiler when it passes the object into the assignment operator.

Comment: 1) Your assignment operator is infinitely recursive, because `std::swap` depends on the assignment operator. 2) Even a proper copy-swap assignment operator does not prevent copy elision.  The copy passed into the assignment operator can be elided, if an r-value is passed in.